# What about to remove listener once we signal the ice candidate to other peer?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I found the following lines of statements (code) in `Pro JavaScript Development` while [googlin](https://books.google.com.np/books?id=pyZIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=icecandidate+with+multiple+peers+at+once&source=bl&ots=PlCQsaukd8&sig=ACfU3U1GK3WMsKKbChHSJCRn6hmLudCzyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA-tmUo6zpAhU3lEsFHQ71AzwQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=icecandidate%20with%20multiple%20peers%20at%20once&f=false).

```
// Google chrome often finds multiple candidates, so let's ensure we only
// ever get the first it supplies by removing the event handler once a 
// candidate has been found

that.peerConnection.onicecandidate = null;
...
that.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(JSON.parse(candidate)))
```

Is it good practice to avoid icecandidate once we find the candidate?

Answer (score 2):

**Nope. Don't do that!**

There are different types of [ice candidates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidateType): `host`, `srflx`, `prflx`, `relay`.

So, it is not guaranteed that on first negotiation between peers they would be connected. They will try to connect with different routes(don't know exactly what I should say) STUN, TURN servers. With the first attempt of negotiation by using STUN server let's assume both peers are connected successfully. But what if they are not connected? They will try to connect with TURN server.

Thus, if we remove the `onicecandidate` listener by assigning it to null after we got the ice candidate, then we're not guaranteed to be connected between peers.