# Ice candidates for local network

Tags: webrtc

Are Ice candidates required if you're using webRTC for the same network?

From reading this [What are ICE Candidates and how do the peer connection choose between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069983/what-are-ice-candidates-and-how-do-the-peer-connection-choose-between-them) they're intermediate connection points to reach the destination. But they're on the same network, so it should be able to go directly go him and thus the public ip is not relevant for this. Can we enter a private ip such as 192.16.x.x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ice candidate is required even for local network.

There isn't required stun or turn server for local network