# In WebRTC, who should be offering ICE candidate to whom?

Tags: webrtc

In WebRTC, 'offer' must be generated by initiating peer (i.e. the caller) and shared with other peer (i.e. the callee) via signaling channel.

The other peer, of she wishes to answer, is supposed to generate 'answer' and send it back to initiating peer. Again, via signaling channel.

In this exchange it is clear who should be preparing which piece of data, and to whom it should be shared.

The next part of the ritual is the gathering of ICE candidates. Both peers will gather their own candidate slowly (trickle ICE) and on each discovered candidate, that candidate should be shared too. Sharing is also to be done via signaling channel

What is not clear to me here is at this point, who should be sharing candidates to whom?

Should caller share with callee? Or the other way around? Or both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ICE candidates are shared with the remote peer. If you think in terms of Offer/Answer

- The offerer will send their ICE Candidates to the answerer
- The answerer will send their ICE Candidates to the offerer

So the answer to your final question would be `both`!

Comment: Think of trickle ICE as an optimization that lets you send offers and answers early, before they contain all the ICE candidates they're supposed to have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm continuing with @Sean DuBois's Answer ( I know this full fill your question, but litle more about this) , Refer this  [Stackoverflow post and My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570120/how-to-debug-the-selection-of-ice-candidate/63581982#63581982)

You will get more clarity on ice gathering.