# Problem with STUN/TURN servers in WEBRTC video app made in MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, video, webrtc, stun, turn

I have hosted a peer to peer meeting react app on netlify. I have used Peerjs for my video purpose. Everything is working as expected except the video. For some networks the video of the the remote person is working and for some others it is not working. I looked up and found out that it may be a STUN/TURN issue. I then implemented all the STUN/TURN servers in my code. However the video is still not getting setup in some cases. In some cases it is working fine, in others the video is not showing up. Herewith, I am attaching th code for the video and the link to the site.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import {io} from "socket.io-client";
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Grid} from "@material-ui/core";
import Peer from 'peerjs';
var connectionOptions =  {
"force new connection" : true,
"reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
"timeout" : 10000,                  
"transports" : ["websocket"]
};
const Videobox = ({isVideoMute,isAudioMute}) => {


var myPeer = new Peer(
  {
    config: {'iceServers': [
      {urls:'stun:stun01.sipphone.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.ekiga.net'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.fwdnet.net'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.ideasip.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.iptel.org'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.schlund.de'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
      {urls:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
      {urls:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
      {urls:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
      {urls:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
      {urls:'stun:stunserver.org'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.softjoys.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.voiparound.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.voipbuster.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.voipstunt.com'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.voxgratia.org'},
      {urls:'stun:stun.xten.com'},
      {
        urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        credential: 'muazkh',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com'
      },
      {
        urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
        username: '28224511:1379330808'
      },
      {
        urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
        username: '28224511:1379330808'
      }
    ]} /* Sample servers, please use appropriate ones */
  }
);
const peers = {}
const [socket, setSocket] = useState()
const {id:videoId} = useParams();
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')

useEffect(()=> {
    const s=io("https://weconnectbackend.herokuapp.com",connectionOptions);
    setSocket(s);
    return () => {
      s.disconnect();
    }
  },[])

// let myVideoStream;
const [myVideoStream, setmyVideoStream] = useState()
const muteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    //setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    //setMuteButton();
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
}

const playStop = () => {
  //console.log('object')
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    //setPlayVideo()
  } else {
    //setStopVideo()
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
}
useEffect(() => {
  if(myVideoStream)
    playStop()
}, [isVideoMute])
useEffect(() => {
  if(myVideoStream)
    muteUnmute()
}, [isAudioMute])

useEffect(() => {
    
  if(socket== null)
      return;
  myPeer.on('open',id=>{
    socket.emit('join-room',videoId,id);
  })
  const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
  myVideo.muted = true
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
    // myVideoStream = stream;
    window.localStream=stream;
    setmyVideoStream(stream);
    console.log(myVideoStream,"myvideostream");
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)
    myPeer.on('call', call => {
      call.answer(stream)
      const video = document.createElement('video')
      call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      })
    })
  
    socket.on('user-connected',userId =>{
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })

    socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
      if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
    })
  })
  
}, [socket,videoId])


function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}

return (

    <div id="video-grid" className="videoStyleFromDiv">
        {/* <Video srcObject={srcObject}/> */}
    </div>
  
)
}

export default Videobox
```

[Website Link](https://we-con-nect.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0):

The TURN servers you are using have been out of commission for a couple of years in the case of the ones taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

Copying credentials from random places is not how TURN works, you will need to run your own servers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am actually pretty new to the concepts of STUN and TURN. I don't know from where to set up my own server. Can you help me out with this? Can you suggest me from where can I set up my own TURN server(preferably a free of cost one if possible)?

Comment: Adding multiple stun/turn is not a good option, this means you are asking your name to multiple person. a single stun/turn config will give you the right answer you want. Also I already answered  in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570120/how-to-debug-the-selection-of-ice-candidate/63581982#63581982   about sturn/turn.

Comment: Can you tell me from where can I get my own TURN/STUN server?

Comment: https://github.com/coturn/coturn is the most commonly used server. "Free" TURN servers don't exist.