# What is a fast, easy to use, customizable way to record a video from a user's webcam and store it that works in all browsers?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, webcam

I'm planning on making a MVC5 application that has the functionality to record a 2 second video from a user's webcam and store it in a separate storage.

I have done some searching but cannot find a clear way on how to collect a video from a webcam. Some options that I found are via Flash (e.g, [Red5 recorder](http://www.red5-recorder.com/)), [SilverLight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [jQuery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). The latter only seems to record images, SilverLight seems a bit of a hassle and Red5 seems to fill my needs.

I also found some C# frameworks with might be best since it will be a MVC5 application. Maybe [Expression Encoded](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4) or [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/) are good choices?

My goal it to collect two seconds video's of users where the user can control when it starts recording and when it finishes. If good means that it is easy to use, customizable and that it has a fast performance, then what is according to you a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question   will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Comment: @Oscar I expect people to answer with their favourite choice and provide some arguments based on facts.

Comment: How do you define "good/best?"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16319470

Comment: @RobertHarvey With good and best in extra-moral sense I mean that it is easy to use, customizable and that it has fast performance. And I found the getUserMedia but that only works in Chrome. It should work cross-browser. I updated the question.

Comment: [This one uses Flash](http://www.fotofriend.com/video-booth).

Comment: Ultimately, I don't know that we can make this decision for you.  You seem to know what the available options are; explore each one and pick the one that best meets your specific requirements.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not know all the available options since I only did a quick Google search. I might be missing something. :-) That is why I hope someone with experience will provide some insights. We'll see what happens. :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: i used [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/) and it's easy to use and you can save the videos as mp4 and i think then it should work as you wish

Comment: @YaserJaradeh Can you tell me wnere you use it for and what you like about it?

Comment: @YaserJaradeh I'm going for AForge since you can integrate it is a .NET framework. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YaserJaradeh It seems AForge cannot be used in a MVC5 Web Application. It is only Windows Forms I believe. Did you use it on the client side?

Comment: i actually used it on the sever side :( sorry if it didn't help you

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [ScriptCam](http://www.scriptcam.com/) with S3 bucket. Works well, but is not free (50 EUR license) if you have a lot of visitors (50+ per day) or a commercial website. It is not customizable apart from the defined JavaScript parameters since it is written in flash. But like I said it does work and I am happy that it is available.

From my search I have concluded there is not yet a way to access webcam via HTML/JavaScript without Flash or SilverLight which works in all modern browsers without using a third-party plugin.