# How to capture video and save it in desk from asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I' trying to build an application using asp.net MVC 4 & c# which basically can capture video from the webcam and save it into the desk , are there any libraries that I can use for that purpose ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can capture video via a web browser using getUserMedia()  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319470/html5-getusermedia-record-webcam-both-audio-and-video.

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.Net is built on the .Net framework to provide additional
>   functionality around **web development**.
>
> ASP.NET MVC 4 is a framework for building scalable, standards-based **web applications** using well-established design patterns.

I guess you mean .NET framework, because as you see MVC4, ASP.NET are designed for web development.

[Here is good example of using web cam in C# with .NET Framework 4.0.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework)