# HTML5 <video>: Recording both audio and video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm struggling to record both video and audio to a single file format (such as mp4). From all the examples I find on the web, getUserMedia can only record sound or video, to 2 different files.
I even managed to record both a video file (webm) and an audio file (.wav), but now I cannot use the `<video>` element to play them both, since it can only accept one valid source. 
I tried merging the 2 files, but there is no sync.

Can anyone please provide an example how to record BOTH audio and video on the same .record function ?

Thanks !

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: This does not answer my problem. This code is for creating 2 different files.

Comment: No it's actually not. Read this answer which has already been asked. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16319470/449688

Comment: Problem is that in all browsers, I get an error in the line: streamRecorder = webcamstream.record();     It says that record is not a function

Comment: That's only the first answer. There are more. If that question doesn't answer your problem, then edit your question to state what you tried and why the other question didn't answer it. Otherwise your questions are the same and it's a duplicate.

Comment: You could try a commercial solution like Nimbb, Ziggeo or AddPipe.